# tableView.beginUpdates is not working iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I was using `tableview.begingUpdates()` to animate the change of my `tableviewcell` heigh (expansion and collision of an image). It was working tip-top on iOS 8.0-9.3. After iOS10.0 it stopped working for an unknown reason. Is anybody facing this issue right now?

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return self.selectedIndexPath && self.selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row ? self.view.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20 : UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Inside the didSelect Method

```
if(shouldExpand){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
        } completion:nil];
}
else{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Pretty basic nothing much going on.

Comment: It's not an answer but more a suggestion: have you tried calling ```reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:``` in between ```beginUpdates``` and ```endUpdates```?

Comment: I have. But it animates with a fade effect not the desired stretch effect.

Comment: else{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
} what do you expect to happen here , you should put ur code in between!

Comment: @M_Waly This code works perfectly on iOS 9+

Comment: Try to refresh the cell by simply calling: `[cell setNeedsLayout]`. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29763829/988169).

Comment: FYI, mine is working in iOS 10 but not in iOS 8 and 9. After using Xcode 8 it drives me crazy for whole day and I just removed all the animation-related codes. FYI [UIView animateWithDuration] in layoutSubviews() too also caused issues, but only running fine in iOS 10. I wonder who is working in Apple iOS department now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that in iOS10.0 the change of the constraints of a superview is pretty much messed up for the subviews constraints. Filed a bug to Apple and waiting for there answer. Reported and here's a [link](https://openradar.appspot.com/324324325)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did was to call `tableView.reloadData()` (Because the cells are already there) after my `.endUpdate()` method is called (I have a delegate method, that informs me when this happens).